# I can't connect my database on Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pymysql

This is the code I need to use to connect the database but it gives me the error shown below.

The code:

%sql mysql+pymysql://root:botsebontle22@localhost:3306/united_nations

The Error:

MetaData.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

I have already installed the necessary packages on my environment but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: That is crazy if that is true because I literally can not see the word bind in your code at all.  Perhaps that is your code, but another line does the bind, but regardless hopefully theJelly has got this for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to downgrade sqlaclchemy to version 1.4.4. Do this by running **pip install sqlalchemy==1.4.4**. after you are done, restart the kernel in jupyter notebook and run all the cells. it should work

Comment: Hi thank you. Quick question, which Python version is compatible with that version of sqlalchemy?